Full-screen notification in React Native that remains open until user interaction
How can I create a full-screen notification in React Native that remains open until the user interacts with it? It will open in background.
I used notifee with the following code:
await notifee.displayNotification({
    title: '<p style="color: #4caf50;"><b>Styled HTMLTitle</span></p></b></p> &#128576;',
    subtitle: '&#129395;',
    body: 'The <p style="text-decoration: line-through; height: 1000px">body can</p> also be <p style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #9c27b0"><i>styled too</i></p> &#127881;!',
    android: {
        channelId: channelId,
        visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC,
        ongoing: true,            // Keeps the notification persistent
        priority: 'high',
        autoCancel: false,
        category: AndroidCategory.CALL,
        importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
        fullScreenAction: {
            id: 'default', // Specifies the action ID for full screen
            mainComponent: 'custom-component',
        }
    },
});

Example image:


When you set autoCancel: false in Notifee, it ensures the notification does not automatically disappear after the user interacts with it (e.g., taps or opens it).
You've already done this, so it should work for you.
Additionally, you've included the following lines:
fullScreenAction: {
  id: 'default', // Specifies the action ID for full screen
  mainComponent: 'custom-component',
}

This ensures the notification will open in full-screen mode. Your setup seems correct. it will be full screen and it will close only in case where user interact with it. if it doesn't your problem will be somewhere else.
Read the link for official Documentations:
https://notifee.app/react-native/reference/notificationandroid#autocancel
https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/behaviour#full-screen
